# Adding and removing events with a HTML form, listing them

Tags: fullcalendar

Are there templates to be able to have an admin page where you can add/remove events? I'm also looking for a way to show all the events as a list as well. I'm not familiar with fullcalendar and it doesn't seem like there are any other alternatives, but the problem is there are no real template that I could find for fullcalendar.

Comment: I'm surprised that with how many people use FullCalendar that I haven't been able to find any html+js code of a way to add events.

Answer (score 1):

Check those out:

1. [CLNDR.js](https://github.com/kylestetz/CLNDR)
2. [jQuery Event Calendar](http://www.vissit.com/projects/eventCalendar/)
3. [wdCalendar](http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-plugins-demo/wdCalendar/sample.php)

Hope it's useful!

Comment: These are some nice suggestions! With CLNDR.js and jQuery Event Calendar, I'm still confused as to how I would create events, though.